# How to get Bitcoin Cash from Multibit HD wallet?

Tags: multibit, bitcoin-cash

Multibit HD still works but is no longer supported so I sent most of my bitcoins to my new ledger nano s hardware wallet.
I now gather there may be bitcoin cash associated with the old multibit wallet that could still be claimed. If so, how can I do that please?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a Bitcoin Cash specific wallet.  I won't recommend a specific one but here is a list:

https://www.bitcoincash.org/#wallets

Use at your own risk.

Comment: Why the down vote with no comment?

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, but the downvote is probably because this answer is not particularly informative or useful at answering the OPs question.